# Unity Camera resets rotation instead of using existing values

Tags: unity, c#, camera, rotation

I'm working on a generic camera rig using mouse inputs, kind of like an RTS camera but it will be used to look at models with as a sort of turntable viewer.

The issue I am having is that when I **rotate** the camera, then **pan**, then try to **rotate** again, the rotation resets to the initial value. I think the issue is that the old rotation values aren't remembered when I begin the new rotate operation, so it resets to the default value (0,0,0,1).

If this is indeed the issue, how should I approach saving the value at the end of the frame, then reuse it in following frames?

[.gif of issue](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CH2kP.jpg)

[Code:](https://gist.github.com/MrMagicPenguin/c921cc435907d17aae8b45aa32eb72ca)

```cs
using System;
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class CameraRigController : MonoBehaviour
{
    public float moveSpeed;
    public float moveTime;
    public float rotationAmount;
    public float zoomAmount;

    public Transform cameraPosition;
    public Quaternion newRotation;
    
    public Vector3 newPosition;
    public Vector3 newZoom;
    
    // mouse rotato
    public Vector3 rotateStartPosition;
    public Quaternion rotateCurrentPosition;

    private float z;
    private float y;
    void Start()
    {
        newPosition = transform.position;
        newRotation = transform.rotation;
        newZoom = cameraPosition.localPosition;
    }
    
    void LateUpdate()
    {
        HandleMovementInput();        
    }

    void HandleMovementInput()
    {
        // Zoom
        if (Input.mouseScrollDelta.y !=0)
        {
            newZoom.x += Input.mouseScrollDelta.y * zoomAmount;
        }
        
        // Pan
        if (Input.GetMouseButton(1))
        {
            z = Input.GetAxis("Mouse X") * moveSpeed;
            y = -Input.GetAxis("Mouse Y") * moveSpeed;
            
            newPosition.z += z;
            newPosition.y += y;
        }
        
        // Rotate
        if (Input.GetMouseButton(0))
        {
            z += Input.GetAxis("Mouse X") * rotationAmount;
            y += Input.GetAxis("Mouse Y") * rotationAmount;
            
            newRotation = Quaternion.Euler(0,z,y);
            rotateCurrentPosition = newRotation;
        }

        transform.position = newPosition;
        transform.rotation = newRotation;
        cameraPosition.localPosition = Vector3.Lerp(cameraPosition.localPosition, newZoom, Time.deltaTime * moveTime);
    }
}
```

Comment: Looks like you're using the same y & z variables to do double-duty, tracking both a pan in progress and a rotation in progress. Have you considered giving each operation its own dedicated variables, rather than trying to share a single data container between unrelated data items this way?

Comment: Oh wow I absolutely am.. i thought those were local variables within the method for some reason. I'll give that a shot, cheers!

Comment: If that solves it for you, be sure to post your solution as an Answer below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to @DMGregory for his input. Adding separate vector variables for rotation and position Z,Y solved the issue.

**Add explicit variables for Position and Rotation Z/Y**

```cs
    private float positionZ;
    private float positionY;
    private float rotationZ;
    private float rotationY;
```

**Use these variables instead for pan, rotate actions**

```cs
    // Pan
        if (Input.GetMouseButton(1))
        {
            positionZ = Input.GetAxis("Mouse X") * moveSpeed;
            positionY = -Input.GetAxis("Mouse Y") * moveSpeed;
            
            newPosition.z += positionZ;
            newPosition.y += positionY;
        }
        
    // Rotate
        if (Input.GetMouseButton(0))
        {
            rotationZ += Input.GetAxis("Mouse X") * rotationAmount;
            rotationY += Input.GetAxis("Mouse Y") * rotationAmount;
            
            newRotation = Quaternion.Euler(0, rotationZ, rotationY);
        }
```

Comment: It might be worth sharing your corrected code as a concrete example for future readers. Don't forget to mark this answer as Accepted after the required waiting period.

Comment: Good call, cheers!